# Close all modals bootstrap

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog

I would like to close all modals with a line of code, I have a code is like this:

```
closeModals() {

    $('#new-user').modal('hide');
    $('#new-project').modal('hide');
    $('#new-task').modal('hide');
}
```

But the problem is that I have more than 20 modals in my project, is there a way of closing all modals without repeating the id of each modal ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can add class to the element you can call just this.

```
$('.my-modals').modal('hide');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select via javascript the class of all your modals and close them.

**Bootstrap < 5**

```js
$('.modal').modal('hide');
```

Bootstrap >= 5

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.modal').forEach(function(modalElem) {
    const myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(modalElem);
    myModal.hide();
});
```